# How to select a tag which contains another tag with a specific value in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an xml that looks like this

```html
<list>
<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <data>123</data>
</item>
<item>
  <id>2</id>
  <data>abc</data>
</item>
</list>
```

Is there any builtin function in nokogiri that allows me to get an `<item>` that have an specific `<id>`?

Something that would look like this:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '
<list>
<item>
  <id>1</id>
  <data>123</data>
</item>
<item>
  <id>2</id>
  <data>abc</data>
</item>
</list>
'

data = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

item = data.xpath("//item:contains('id', '2')")
```

I could achieve it by:

```rb
item = data.xpath("//item").select {|d| d.xpath("id").text == "2"}
```

But is there any builtin way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "builtin"? Have you tried [Slop](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#slop-1) mode? Probably something you're looking for.  
Or are you looking for something like `data.xpath("//id[text() = '2']/parent::node()")`

Comment: @DiMithras Yes `data.xpath("//id[text() = '2']/parent::node()")` is what I was looking for. But how can I make the same using `Slop`?

Comment: Well, `Slop` is just a decorator that will make it look more "builtin", that's why I asked what do you mean by that.

Comment: @DiMithras I meant a way that does not need to to use `.select`

Comment: Ohh… than for `Slop` I have to use it, can't imagine any other solution. Feels like my previous `xpath` thing is what you need. Anyway, added a descriptive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Following the comments I'll put it in the answer.</sub>

```ruby
item = data.xpath("//id[text() = '2']/parent::node()")
```

This is a solution with **xpath**. Instead of iterating through items one can directly access what is needed. If I do a [benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) on this solution it shows **0.000068** compared to your approach `item = data.xpath("//item").select {|d| d.xpath("id").text == "1"}` which scores **0.000121**, basically a 2 times improvement.

---

As for [Slop](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#slop-1), it's a decorator that will make your code look more "*builtin*", native, whatever. First you'll need to change the way how you acquire data: `data = Nokogiri::Slop(xml)`, Slop goes instead of XML. The code to achieve what you need will be:

```ruby
item = data.list.item.select{|x| x.id.text == '2'}
```

As you see it lacks those **xpath** strings, utilizes ruby methods:

> The Slop decorator implements **method_missing** such that methods may be used instead of CSS or XPath. [source: w3cub](https://docs.w3cub.com/nokogiri/nokogiri)

So, yeah, it looks cool 
However it requires **0.000137** to complete, so there is no boost in optimization compared to your solution. If you don't care about optimization and you care about readability and fanciness of your code, this `Slop` approach could be a nice solution.

Comment: This is the best footnote I have ever read: "Slop [1](https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#fn:1); 1. Don't use this...3. No, really, don't use this. If you use it, don't report bugs. 4. You've been warned!"